# Capture simulated React aplication for Stress Test with JMeter

Tags: ios, reactjs, jmeter

I need to record the usage of an App for a Stress Test. The App it's coded on React Native and im simulating an iOS phone to record the funcionalities with JMeter.

I used to record Web and HTML5 Apps with Chrome. It's any way to capture the iOS Simulator?

Thanks and have a happy new year :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "usage of the app"?

If you need to monitor application-specific metrics like CPU, memory, network, battery usage, etc. - you won't be able to do this with JMeter, take a look at [Instruments](https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/xcode-instruments-time-profiler/) application and its capabilities when it comes to profiling iOS apps.

With JMeter you can simulate hundreds/thousands of concurrent devices simultaneously accessing the [backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontend_and_backend) server or the database, if this is what you're looking for - you can record the application network footprint using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html). Just make sure to install JMeter's self-signed certificate onto your device (or simulator), the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's generated in JMeter's "bin" folder when you start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.

You will also need to [enable full trust](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT204477) for the JMeter's certificate, see [Configure Apple Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285377-Configure-Apple-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording) guide for more details.

Once you record the test scenario "skeleton" you should be able to replay it with increased number of users after [correlating](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) the dynamic parameters and performing necessary parameterization.

Comment: I was talking abount JMeter and concurrencies :) Thanks for your time! Ill test it.